# VSCode exit code 9009 popup when manually exit the terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I stop the Python debugger and exit the terminal, I receive a popup notification in the lower-right of VSCode:

[image]

Because I stop the debugger and exit the terminal dozens of times per day, this is a nuisance. I could just ignore it (there is only ever one opened - and it doesn't stop anything from working), but then it's always there sitting on top of code I want to see.

IS THERE some setting (perhaps in settings.json) that would disable this message?

Failing that, is there some way to auto-close it on a 1-sec timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your settings.json: `"terminal.integrated.showExitAlert": false`

[Option to disable alert The terminal process terminated with exit code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/40503)